# Create a constructor method that allows declaration/initialize in a single line

Tags: .net, vb.net

If I use one of the built in Types in `VB.NET` I can declare and initialize in one short line ...

```
Dim foo As String = "Привет мир"
```

I've created a class "bar" with the following overloaded constructor method...

```
Public Class bar

    Private fText As String

    Public Sub New()
        fText = ""
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal value As String)
        fText = value
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Text() As String
        Get
            Return fText
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

How do I write the constructor so that instead of doing the following I can do the shorter version of declaration/initialisation?

Currently with `bar` I do this:

```
Dim myBar As bar
myBar = New bar("Привет мир")
```

How can I set `bar` so this shorter version is possible?:  `Dim myBar As bar = "Привет мир"`

Comment: Couldn't you just do `Dim myBar As bar = New bar("Привет мир")` or something similar?

Comment: cheers Tim; so many ways of doing things in `.NET` just a case of trying to make myself aware of them. (+ I'm coming from 10 yrs of `VBA` which doens't allow these shortcuts)

Comment: You can omit the double type name and just use:  Dim myBar As New bar("Привет мир")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make the property with a public setter:

```
Public Class bar
    Public Property Text() As String

    Sub New()
        ' set a default value for the property
        Text = ""
    End Sub
End Class
```

you could use class initializer syntax:

```
Dim bar = New bar With {.Text = "Привет мир"}
```

With this syntax you could set any public property when instantiating the object. You do not need specific constructors for that:

```
Dim bar = New bar With {.Text = "Привет мир", .Foo = "foo", .Bar = "bar"}
```

If the property should be readonly and initialized only through the constructor then your current code is fine.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is doable with implicit conversion operator:

```
class bar
{
 //...
    public static implicit operator bar(string value)
    {
        return new bar(value);
    }
}
```

Although I would not recommend using this feature for purpose of shortening construction line this would be a bad practice.

ps sorry for c# code snippet.

Comment: Here's a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/yf7b9sy7.aspx) to the VB topic on the same (not worth posting as a separate answer) VB uses the words Widening and Narrowing instead of implicit and explicit.